# Looking for a CLI e-mail sender that supports OAUTH 2.0

Tags: linux, email, security, command-line

I want to be able to send gmail messages from a raspberry pi, ideally from a single line of a shell script - I know I can use a mail server other than gmail that supports less secure login options, or go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and change the settings there - that is NOT what I want to do, as I would prefer to use the newer version of OAUTH

There seem to be many e-mail options, most with more features than what I care about, but I don't see OAUTH support as an "advertised" feature (note: I don't want to receive e-mails or check them, nor do I care for a GUI) - what is the simplest way to achieve this?

I would prefer free and open source, and also relatively easy to setup/configure, in that order as far as priorities go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted, *and extremely well written*, StackOverflow Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445523/python-smtplib-is-sending-mail-via-gmail-using-oauth2-possible) covers how to do this from python - without lowering the security settings so all you need to do is:

1. follow the instructions for getting your token
2. adapt the section about sending a mail into a script that takes an email address, title and message as inputs (*make sure your script starts with the python [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)* `#!/usr/bin/env python` - *if running windows you need to make sure that your script name ends with .py*
3. place the script somewhere on your path, *or somewhere that you are going to run it from*, and
4. set it to executable with `chmod +x`*/path/to/your/script* (you should skip this if running Windows)

This solution:

- Uses the industry-standard OAuth 2.0 protocol.
- Is Free & Open Source.
- Should work on any computer/OS that has python installed and is connected to the internet. *Raspberrian has python as do most linux machines, OS/X etc and it is installable on Windows*

Answer (score 2):

I just came by your thread and might not understand your requirement correctly. But if I understood correctly, I think you can use git to send emails with Google Oauth2.

```
$ git send-email --smtp-pass your-Oauth2-app-pwd 
                 --smtp-user your.email@gmail.com 
                 --smtp-server smtp.gmail.com 
                 --smtp-encryption tls 
                 --smtp-server-port 587 
                 --to your-friend@gmail.com
                 mail-content.txt
```

This is how I am sending patches using my Google account email.